# Node.js bug ? function's return value change when stored as variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

Well, I won't talk much...
I've been using node.js as a WebSocket server, and I've got this *problem?* :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaJH.png)

(expected output is: 'works here')

Here are the lines that do this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1i9O.png)

More images :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OZe0.png)
(expected output is : 'works')

I mean, when the value is stored as a variable, it changes ??
Is that some kind of bug in nodeJS or v8 engine ??
(probably , it's 99% i'm wrong ;)

Here's the function's source :

```
websocket.prototype.decodeWebSocketMessage = function decodeWebSocketMessage(native_data){
var message = native_data;//data.slice(start, end);
var FIN = (message[0] & 0x80);
var RSV1 = (message[0] & 0x40);
var RSV2 = (message[0] & 0x20);
var RSV3 = (message[0] & 0x10);
var Opcode = message[0] & 0x0F;
var mask = (message[1] & 0x80);
var length = (message[1] & 0x7F);
var nextByte = 2;
if (length === 126) {// length = next 2 bytes
    nextByte += 2;
} else if (length === 127){// length = next 8 bytes
    nextByte += 8;
}

var maskingKey = null;
if (mask){
    maskingKey = message.slice(nextByte, nextByte + 4);
    nextByte += 4;
}

var payload = message.slice(nextByte, nextByte + length);

if (maskingKey){
    for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++){
        payload[i] = payload[i] ^ maskingKey[i % 4];
    }
}
return payload.toString().split("\n")[0];
```

}

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code in your question

Comment: Also, post your code and not image links, we can't really help you using images

Comment: same thing as .toString() , nothing changes

Comment: It's hard to help you given the sparse information but as a suggestion, because you think you've found a bug in V8 or Node: http://pragmatictips.com/26

If you are looking for help, create a code snipped that reproduces the problem and post it here. When I do that, I often even find my problem on my own in the process.

Comment: @DanielKhan , I still don't know if that's a bug, or probably i've made some mistakes, but i want help to know that

Comment: @aymenayoo please add also the output and what you'd expect instead.

Comment: the output is some unreadable text, and the expected is a human-readable text ^^ ('works' here)

Comment: try calling `decodeWebSocket()` twice, but assign both to the output variable. I suspect it's the second call that gives the correct value for some reason (you're probably double-encoding the data accidentally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `decodeWebStream` mutates the input variable d. This probably combined with an error elsewhere in your code double-encoding your data is probably leading to the second call of `decodeWebStream` giving you the correct value (but not first or third).

Comment: This is what happened exactly ! thank u for the help